# What happens if I run svn update while another svn update is already running?

Tags: svn

We have an automated script that runs "svn update". The updates can be potentially large (100+MB of binary data)

It is possible that the script could get run while a previous instance of the script is still running.

Will this cause any problems? Will the second instance of "svn update" realise that there is another svn update process already running on the same directory? And if so, what will it do?

Comment: Are you using an official build or official source? or a 3rd party client?

Comment: The official windows command line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When svn performs any actions on a working copy, svn puts a lock on it. The lock is removed after the operation is completed.

If than another svn instance detects that the working copy is locked, it will stop the operation with error.

Comment: The exact error is "svn: Working copy '.' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)"

Answer (score 1):

It will detect it and queue the update operations.